# Inverting display colors in iOS app when button in pressed

Tags: ios, accessibility

I want to invert all the colors that the screen displays while the user is in my app when the user taps a button.

So basically I want to know if it is possible to turn on the accessibility option 'invert colors' for only my app when the user so chooses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change accessibility options in-app, or anything similar, really—the only *simple* option you have are to manually invert the color of views on the screen (which would be easy if it's always the same screen, and just a few bits of text and a couple UIView's).

Or, for more complicated views, get your view as an image (see `[view.layer renderInContext:c]` and `CGBitmapContextCreateImage(c)` for more), inver the images' colors, and then draw the image above your current view. It might not be the fastest option, but it may be your only one.

Comment: Looking into Apple’s Watch (stock) app, in some sceeen it runs as if user turned on invert. It’s done programmatically. Just wonder if it secret recipe Apple own.